# How can I capture a user define target in first page and track the target in second page in Vuforia?

Tags: vuforia, virtual-reality

How can I capture a user define target in first page and track the target in second page in **Vuforia**?

Answer (score 0):

By page, I assume you mean "scene". The thing is you cant. The User Defined Target can not be passed to other scenes. The only way is to recapture a user defined target on your second scene. Though, this can be done using Predefined targets.